# wso2 Identity Server - SSO - application with specific rights

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

Currently I have two applications that handle each user and rights.

I wanted to install and configure a WSO2 IS authentication server, and using SSO, for this two applications

Can I use WSO2IS in my case? if yes, how to use it and how the authentication server can handle those rights that are already in the application

Thanks

Comment: Appreciate if you could give more details on what you mean by rights here. You can easily do SSO between your two applications with wso2 identity server.

Comment: Do you want to configure user permissions at the OAuth2 server? What reason do you have for that?

Comment: I have two applications that both handle rights. The users of these applications are clients. These customers have the right to view only their data and not those of other customers.
I do not know if I can move this rights management from both applications to the authorization server.
I thought about using wso2is for that.
Do you have an idea if this is feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ESO2IS SSO - you can recieve next information of user:
profile - username, tenant, roles, user_id

Also throw Entitlement service of IS you can check permission for resources. Resources need be described in XAMCL format and deploy to IS.

If you want to check right of access to some data (row of database tables) you need to do it on DSS and ESB layer.

Comment: is that specifique to wso2is ? is there other authorization server who can do that? thanks

Comment: I think no one authorization server can control permission to user data. Your applications must do it by themself base on user-profile data.

Comment: So we will have redundant data. The user data must be stored in the database of the application and in the database of the authorization server

Comment: User data - you mean user profile or user data that he add in you applications?
You can add user_ids of your applications to WSO2IS user profile. And when user will authenticate by SSO - your application will recieve list of user_id from profile. And you would be can to create correct session in each applications by its user_id.

Comment: So if I understood correctly. In the database of the authentication server, I will store the data relative to the user (id_user, name, first name, mail, ....) and in the base of my application I will store the (id_user and rights that allow to visualize Some data)
The link between the authorization server and my application, to manage the rights, is going to be the id_user field

Comment: In WSO2IS you can use XAML Entitlement. You describe different resources and permission for them. For example you can make follow:

Comment: You want to make some section of your application visible to user that have some roles:  
1. You create role in IS  
2. Invent resource name for you section of app - example http://private_section  
3. Create XACML (read about it) mapping permission/roles to this resources  
4. In you app you can call wsdl Entitlement and ask: WSO2IS.isCurrentUserHaveRightsToPrivateSection  
5. WSO2IS return you information of have permission ot not

Comment: thank you. I will try to implement using your method